# What does the first character in these CSS classes refer to?

Tags: css, naming-conventions

I see more and more people prepending their class names with a leading character. For example 'o-' and 'a-' in the following snippet:

```
<div class="o-main-header">
  <div class="o-main-header__logo">
    <a class="m-svg-icon o-main-header__logo-svg">...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What do these characters refer to? Is this part of BEM or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: probably some templating system, but to css itself it's meaningless. you could call the classes "fred" or "kittens". it's just a name as far as CSS is concerned.

Comment: which site did you see them at?

Comment: @atha A few. They're on Brad Frost's 'Atomic Design' templater for example: http://demo.patternlab.io/?p=organisms-header.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:
http://csswizardry.com/2015/03/more-transparent-ui-code-with-namespaces/

They relate to the scope of each class.

Comment: this is called BEM methodology, you can find more info [here](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/)

Comment: I'm familiar with BEM, but I don't see any mention of the leading namespace characters on that page nor in the BEM documentation - so I was wondering whether it was part of a different naming convention.